# TeX logo with LuaTeX and Linux Biolinum O/G

Tags: fonts, luatex

Something is wrong with TeX and LaTeX logos with the font Linux Biolinum O under LuaTeX. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\LinBioO{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\LinBioG{Linux Biolinum G}

\begin{document}
{\LinBioO\LaTeX}\quad{\LinBioG\LaTeX}
\end{document}
```

With LuaTeX, I get

[image: this],

while with XɘTeX you get the correct result:

[image: result]

I did not really try other fonts, except Linux Libertine O and G, which both give a correct alignment of the ‘E’. Is the problem specific to the Linux Biolinum O font?

Comment: I added the images for you. Tip: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Might be that bug with some Linux Libertine fonts having wrong x height font dimen, what is the output of `\the\fontdimen5\font` (just after each font)?

Comment: @KhaledHosny With LuaTeX, I get 1.01 pt for Linux Biolinum O and 4.32129 pt for Linux Biolinum G. Under XɘTeX, the values are respectively 4.32 pt and 4.32129 pt. What explains this difference?

Comment: IIRC, XeTeX ignores the x height value in the font and calculates it by itself, in LuaTeX (or rather `luaotfload` package) we use the value supplied by the font. The proper solution here is to fix the font.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Alright. Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: @MarcROGERdeCAMPAGNOLLE: +1, but don't use `minimal` for MWEs. Use e.g. `article` instead. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/4012

Comment: @doncherry: I take note of your remark. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @KhaledHosny "The proper solution here is to fix the font." - right. The `os2_xheight` is 101 which is in accordance to the `\the\fontdimen5` above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it is a bug in the font, with LuaTeX we can “patch” fonts on the fly, and here is a possible fix:

```lua
\directlua {
local function fix_biolinum_xheight(fontdata)
  if fontdata.fullname:find("Linux Biolinum") then
    if fontdata.characters[string.byte("x")] then
      fontdata.parameters.x_height = fontdata.characters[string.byte("x")].height
    end
  end
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("luaotfload.patch_font", fix_biolinum_xheight, "mypatch.fix_biolinum_xheight")
}
```

Adding those lines just after loading `fontspec` should do the trick.