# A bug in fontspec, lua(la)tex, or the Junicode font?

Tags: luatex, fontspec

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{HelveticaNeue}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Consolas}
\begin{document}
\noindent
some ordinary text\newline
{\sffamily some sans-serif text}\newline
{\ttfamily some monospaced text}
\end{document}
```

On a MacBook running MacTeX2012 and MacOSX 10.7.5, this MWE produces the following output when run under LuaLaTeX:

[image]

but the following (and rather more pleasing) output when run under XeLaTeX:

[image]

Obviously, something's not working quite right under LuaLaTeX. My question is: Is this a bug (a) caused by an error in implementing the `Scale=MatchLowercase` option of fontspec/luatex, (b) caused by a poorly-specified parameter in the `Junicode` font file, or (c) are there two separate bugs at work?

A work-around is to specify `[Scale=0.83]` for `HelveticaNeue` and `[Scale=0.88]` for `Consolas`. Naturally, though, I'd like to employ a somewhat more automated method to get the scaling of the sans and mono fonts adjusted to the size of the text font.

Comment: It seems a problem specific to Junicode; with other main fonts it doesn't happen.

Comment: Confirmed with MiKTeX 2.9, and agree with @egreg. This should probably go on https://sourceforge.net/projects/junicode/ .

Comment: There were a similar (or actually the same?) issue with Linux Libertine mentioned here on TeX.sx, but I can’t find it now. If I rememeber correctly, Luatex relies on what is indicated by the font, XeTeX computes the x-height itself.

Comment: It could be this one: [TeX logo with LuaTeX and Linux Biolinum O/G](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47157/tex-logo-with-luatex-and-linux-biolinum-o-g).

Comment: @doncherry - I've submitted a bug report to the site you listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FontForge has obviously some difficulties to export fonts with "correct" x-height set to be usable with `luaotfload`. So I'd say it is both a bug in FontForge and `luaotfload` and it should be fixed in both.

Comment: According to [Khaled's comment](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3576126&group_id=158636&atid=808625), this bug doesn't occur anymore in the latest Fontforge. A fixed version of Junicode will be on its way soon.

Answer (score 6):

Version 0.7.7 of Junicode released today (2012-11-17) fixes this problem. Go to http://junicode.sf.net.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's great to see another creator of an amazing resource here!